# В какой таблице хранит роли mariadb

Tags: mariadb

В какой таблице хранятся роли или описание их?

Comment: А что вы называете ролью?

Comment: @Smithson https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-role/

Comment: @Smithson https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql.user
User - название роли
Поле is_role в положение Y